# What is the terminology for the report file that generates reports?

Tags: report, reporting, terminology

I am a bit confused of how to present to users the two different concepts; the file that generates the report given data and the final report.

We usually use the same term as `Report` and depending on the context we can understand if this is the report generation file or the final report. This normally is not a problem because the report generation file is created by developers and the end user only see the final report.

In my application I have to describe both of these concepts to my end users and I am pretty confused because I cannot find a proper terminology for this.

Comment: "Report" vs "report instance" or "report template" vs "report"?

Comment: I am closer to use `Report` and `Report definition`

Answer (score 1):

"Template" is the term I would use, it's been around for a *very* long time (I remember using the term template for mail merge operations before the PC was even a thing).

Basically, the template shows how the data is used to create the final output, in your case:

```
+----------+    +------+
| Report   |    | Data |
| template |    +------+
+----------+        |
     |              |      +--------+
     +--------------+----> | Report |
                           +--------+
```